# How to set not italic or not bold?

Tags: fonts

It is well known that you can make the font italic or bold using \textit{} or \textbf{}. However, if I have an italic or bold font, what command can I use to make it nonitalic or nonbold?

Comment: For italic use `\emph` instead of `\textit`

Comment: Ok thanks, but if I keep getting italic or bold font in the output pdf, what command can I use to get regular font?

Comment: By regular I mean nonitalic and nonbold.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can use `\normalfont`

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
 \textit{Some italic and {\normalfont non italic} text}

 \textbf{Some bold and {\normalfont non bold} text}

 \emph{Some italic and {\normalfont non italic} text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don;t you just use `\textnormal{...}` instead of using `{\normalfont ...}`?

Comment: You may want to mention that using `{\normalfont ...}` does not insert an automatic italics correction at the transition from the italic to the upright font shape. In contrast, using an inner `\emph{...}` instruction, a `\textup{...}` instruction, or a `\textnormal{...}` instruction (but not an inner `{\em ...}` construct) generate an automatic italics correction.

Comment: @daleif what is the difference?

Comment: @lucidbrot easier to read

Comment: @lucidbrot - In addition, the `\textnormal{...}` approach takes care to insert italics corrections as needed; the `{\normalfont ...}` does not.

Comment: I wasn't able to use `\normalfont` to say "make this local piece of text bold but not italic"; In contrast, using `textup` as @Mico suggested removes italic without blocking bold.

Answer (score 77):

For the purpose of this discussion, I will assume that you use either `\textbf{...}` or `{\bfseries ...}` to generate **bold text**, and either `\textit{...}`, `\emph{...}`, or `{\itshape ...}` to generate *italic text*. These methods can be combined to get ***bold italic text***, viz., `\textbf{\textit{...}}` or `{\bfseries\itshape ...}`.

- To cancel/override just the *italic* font shape, while leaving the (**bold** or non-bold) font weight unchanged, use either `\textup{...}` or `{\upshape ...}`:

  ```
    \textit{Some italic and some \textup{non italic} text}

    {\itshape Some italic and some {\upshape non italic} text}
  ```

  The `\emph{...}` method can be nested:

  ```
    \emph{Some italic and some \emph{non italic} text}
  ```

  Note that whereas the `\textit{...}` and `\emph{...}` methods take care to insert a so-called *italic correction* in the transitions from italic to non-italic text, the `{\upshape ...}` method does not.
- To override just the bold font weight, while leaving the (*italic* or upright) font shape unchanged, use either `\textmd{...}` or `{\mdseries ...}`:

  ```
    \textbf{Some bold and some \textmd{non bold} text}

    {\bfseries Some bold and some {\mdseries non bold} text}
  ```
- To force both normal font *weight* and normal font *shape* simultaneously, the preceding methods can be combined. *Unless the font face default has been reset earlier* (to `\ttfamily` or `\sffamily`, say; see the comment by @JonathanLandrum below), one can also use either `\textnormal{...}` or `{\normalfont ...}` to force both normal font weight and shape:

  ```
    \textbf{\textit{Some bold-italic, \textmd{non-bold italic}, \textup{non-italic bold}, and \textmd{\textup{{upright\slash non-bold} text}}.}

    {\itshape\bfseries Some bold-italic, {\mdseries non-bold italic}, {\upshape non-italic bold}, and {\mdseries\upshape upright\slash non-bold} text.}
  ```

---

The results generated by these methods are illustrated in the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}

Some normal, i.e., upright and non-bold, text.
 
\medskip
\textit{Some italic and some \textup{upright} text.}

\emph{Some italic and some \emph{upright} text.}

{\itshape Some italic and some {\upshape upright} text.}


\medskip
\textbf{Some bold and some \textmd{non-bold} text.}

{\bfseries Some bold and some {\mdseries non-bold} text.}

\medskip
\textbf{\textit{Some bold-italic, \textmd{non-bold italic}, \textup{non-italic bold}, and \textmd{\textup{upright\slash non-bold}} text}.}

{\itshape\bfseries Some bold-italic, {\mdseries non-bold italic}, {\upshape non-italic bold}, and {\mdseries\upshape upright\slash non-bold} text.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be noted that `\normalfont` will change the font face, as well, whereas the combination of `\upshape` and `\mdseries` will not. So if you are using this in combination with, for example, `\ttfamily`, the effect will be undone by the latter use of `\normalfont`.

Comment: @JonathanLandrum - Many thanks for pointing out this inaccuracy in my answer. I've updated the answer to fix it.

Comment: May also be worth noting that `\mdseries`/`\textmd` will also reser xondensed/extended/etc. and `\upshape`/`\textup` will also reset small caps, unless you also load `fontaxes`.