# How do I mark text as never to be emphasized?

Tags: emphasis

An `\emph` inside another cancels the emphasis.  But what if I want to make
sure something is never emphasized, even if the surrounding emphasis is
removed?  `\textrm` doesn't turn off `ItalicFeatures` defined for the font
family.

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225273/134144

Comment: @leandriis, thanks.  The answer is `\textup`.

Comment: it doesn't really matter, but "`\emph` inside another cancels the emphasis"  is the wrong way to think of it, better to say `\emph` always emphasises the text by choosing a visually distinct font style"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: @Toothrot   :-)..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - So no matter what style you are using \emph will change it to something else?  I guess there is no way stop it then.  Well, \let\emph=\relax

Comment: @JohnKormylo the default definition toggles between upright and italic, but it explicitly isn't a font change (the command to get italic is \textit not \emph) so a document class might define \emph to be bold or red or whatever