# How to undo bold and italic text in braces?

Tags: bold, italic

Is there a command to nullify, override or cancel any font style in the text in braces?

Something like:

`\nullifystyle{sample text: \textit{this should be not italic} and \textbf{this should be not bold}}`

`\normalfont`, `\textnormal`,`\textup` and `\upshape`do the very opposite. 
See: [How to set not italic or not bold?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225267/how-to-set-not-italic-or-not-bold/225273#225273)

Use case: I need it to recall pieces of text from other part of the document, but to override the font style. A MWE would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\nullifystyle}{???} %is there already a command for this? or how to define it?

\newcommand{\textsample} {some normal text, \textit{some italic} and \textbf{some bold}}

Here I would like to write \textsample. \par

Here  \nullifystyle{\textsample} \ should be typed  totally with normal font style.


\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, i.e. what's the use case for this?

Comment: @remco I edited the question with a MWE, thanks

Comment: I still don't see in what kind of situations you would use this. Is it possible to enlighten us? The best thing I can think of is something like "note that if you send the text given above in a telegram, it will lose the formatting and just look like this: ...".

Comment: @pst in the document I'm compiling  I decided that Section Titles must not have any word in italic (e.g. foreign words). But when i recall section title name with `\nameref` the italic words must be correctly typesetted. So this command is pretty useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locally redefine `\selectfont` not to honor changes in shape and series:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nullifystyle}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\sv@f@shape{\f@shape}%
  \edef\sv@f@series{\f@series}%
  \let\sv@selectfont\selectfont
  \def\selectfont{%
    \fontshape{\sv@f@shape}%
    \fontseries{\sv@f@series}%
    \sv@selectfont
  }%
  #1%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\nullifystyle{sample \emph{text}: \textit{this should be not italic}
  and \textbf{this should be not bold}\textsuperscript{test}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It works the same if you use a macro like in your example

```
\newcommand{\sampletext}{sample \emph{text}: \textit{this should be not italic}
  and \textbf{this should be not bold}\textsuperscript{test}}

\nullifystyle{\sampletext}
```

Comment: This also works pretty well!

Comment: @peppino It doesn't require to know in advance what commands to nullify.

Answer (score 5):

You could redefine the commands that you need to nullify something like the following.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\noop[1]{#1}
\newcommand\nullifystyle[1]{\begingroup\let\textit\noop\let\textbf\noop
  #1\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\textit{This should be italic} and \textbf{this should be bold}.

\nullifystyle{\textit{This should not be italic} and \textbf{this
    should not be bold}}.

\textit{This should be italic} and \textbf{this should be bold}.
\end{document}
```

But I think it would be best if you explained something of what you need this for, and then probably a better solution can be suggested.

Comment: your solution works very well. I added a MWE to my question to give more context and see if other solutions are possible.