# How to set not underlined?

Tags: fonts, underline

- `\textit` is canceled by `\textup`
- `\itshape` is canceled by `\upshape`
- `\textbf` is canceled by `\textmd`
- `\bfseries` is canceled by `\mdseries`
- `\normalfont` cancels everything

**What cancles `\underline`?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}\ttfamily
\textit{Some italic and some \textup{upright} text.}\\
{\itshape Some italic and some {\upshape upright} text.}\\
\textbf{Some bold and some \textmd{non-bold} text.}\\
{\bfseries Some bold and some {\mdseries non-bold} text.}\\
\underline{Some underlined and some {\normalfont non-underlined} text.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Inspired by [question “How to set not italic or not bold?”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225267/1236)

Comment: You may want to consider the `\emph` command, which works in a "nested" way: In `abc \emph{def \emph{ghi} jkl} mno`, the "inner" emphasized string ("ghi") is typeset using the upright font shape by default. The `ulem` ("**u**nder**l**ine **em**phasis"?) package does something interesting to `\emph` (unless the option `normalem` is set): an "outer" `\emph` generates underlined text, and an "inner" `\emph` generates double-underlined text.  One could probably hack the package so that inner `\emph` material is typeset *without* underlining; this might look weird, though.

Comment: The `ulem` package also provides the command `\uline`, which is much more useful than `underline`: The former command allows line-breaking between words (but not hyphenation within words), whereas the latter doesn't allow any line-breaking.

Comment: See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9552/24974) and the [link therein](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-underline.html) where it explains `\underline` is a quick fix added in LaTeX that uses `\hbox` and the math underbar. The box doesn't end until the braces are closes, so everything in between is underlined (and linebreaks are prevented.)

Comment: your examples with fonts are not really related to the `\underline` question, if you switch fonts you can easily switch to a different font within that region. But `\underline` is more like `\fbox` if you box a run of text there is no particularly easy way to break out of that box, so you would have to redefine the underlining command to just underline your outer phrases and not underline the middle section. You can't from  inside `\underline` stop the rule being drawn.

Comment: Thanks, @all. I solved the my current intricate problem, which gave rise to this question, with ``l3regex``/``expl3``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TeX `\underline` is a math-mode primitive, meaning that

```
$\underline{abc}$
\bye
```

yields an underlined *abc*, while

```
\underline{abc}
\bye
```

raises an error.

LaTeX makes a wrapper around this (`latex.ltx` lines 5043-5047)

```
\let\@@underline\underline
\def\underline#1{%
  \relax
  \ifmmode\@@underline{#1}%
  \else $\@@underline{\hbox{#1}}\m@th$\relax\fi}
```

Here, first the original primitive is stored under the name `\@@underline`, and then `\underline` is redefined to work also in text mode by putting its content in an `\hbox` (say goodbye to line breaks `:-)`) and then calling the (original) `\@@underline` in inline math `$...$`. So the short answer to your question is: there is nothing which cancels `\underline`.

One might hack e.g. into the `ulem` package to obtain something like what you want with `\uline`, but that's a quite different story.